# How do I open the keyholes?

Tags: the-end-is-nigh

How do I open the keyholes found in each chapter?

[image: Keyhole in Arid Flats 12]

This is the second keyhole I’ve found and I cannot figure out how to open it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Could contain spoilers:

> According to [this](http://steamcommunity.com/app/583470/discussions/1/1457328927828846874/) question in the Steam Community, there is a master key in a later level of the game, the Machine (screen 14).